# Google app stopped working on lumia 950

Tags: google, lumia-950

A few days ago Google app stopped working on my Lumia 950. I can search something but instead of showing the website or information I'm looking for I get a message saying"could not connect to the server. Please try again". There's no problem with my internet connection though and all the other apps work without problems.

Comment: I just installed the app on my Lumia 950 and the same thing happens. I guess whatever back-end service the app used has been taken down. Frankly, I'm surprised it worked as long as it did.

Comment: I also have this problem, reload this app from store. If it, didn't help, try to restore your phone.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as Google has [removed the app from the store](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=de&sl=de&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwindowsarea.de%2F2018%2F09%2Foffizielle-google-app-nicht-mehr-im-microsoft-store-auffindbar%2F). I guess they also discontinued the backend service as Indrek mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

It might be time to install something like PAWA and get the PWA versions of these apps installed on your phone.
https://www.microsoft.com/p/pawa/9mv27cw02vnt